# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, when running unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, xampp, phpunit, codeception

when I try to run my unit tests, I get this error

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
>   in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library 'curl' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could
>   not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\gd2 (The specified
>   module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified
>   module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP
>   Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The
>   specified module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll
>   (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The
>   specified module could not be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll
>   (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP
>   Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable
>   to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite
>   (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to
>   load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  Cannot open
>   '\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
>
> > Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'bz2' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\bz2 (The specified module could not be found.),
> >     \xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
> >     in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.),
> >     \xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be
> >     found.)) in Unknown on line 0
> >
> > Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: \xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be
> >     found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could
> >     not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified module could not be found.))
>   in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried:
>   \xampp\php\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.),
>   \xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could
>   not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl.dll'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not
>   be found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll.dll (The specified
>   module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll'
>   (tried: \xampp\php\ext\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be
>   found.), \xampp\php\ext\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module
>   could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0

Could somebody help me ? Thanks.
Running in PHPstorm, Win 10

Answer (score 27):

You may need to edit your `php.ini` file and restart the server. Add absolute paths in `php.ini` configuration. It worked for xampp server in my windows 8.1 machine. 
example: 
`extension_dir="\xampp\php\ext"` to
`extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext"`

Reference: [How to fix PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_curl.dll'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027013/how-to-fix-php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-ext-php-cu/25027173)

Edit:
Additionally for my some cases, needs to edit
`browscap="xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"` to
`browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"`

Comment: Specifically, if that link goes down, it would be very unclear what needs to be edited in the php.ini file.  Please edit to add that information.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's was the problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just comment out `;extension=pdo_sqlite` in php.ini if you don't need it. It was enabled by default in my configuration and the error message is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the b2z module for php.
Which is normally included in the php package for windows

I would suggest reinstalling php or manually moving the package from the download to the correct folder or switching to a vagrant environment.

**Download:**

https://windows.php.net/download/

In the folder ext/bz2

Move these folder contents over to the according folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same problem after updating my php version from 7.0 to the latest version which is 8.1.3 as for now , the solution I used was :-

Just comment the extension in the php.ini found in (C:\xampp\php\php.ini)
**extension=gd2**

Note: comment by prefixing semicolon at the start

Answer (score 1):

In your *php.ini* file,
find text=> `extension=gd2`
and make it `;extension=gd2`

Answer (score 0):

I have fought with this for the last 12 hours on my Windows 10 box. For anyone having the same trouble I am having, you need to edit the php.ini to call out the full name of the DLL file. I had to change pdo_sqlite to php_pdo_sqlite.dll and sqlite3 to php_sqlite3.dll.

Answer (score 0):

after adding php ext dir in php.ini, i also needed to add php dir to windows path (environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

For windows 10 users, make open "XAMP" programe, then at apache click button "config"
then edit "php.ini".

#1- remove the semicolon (;) before this line

```
extension=php_gd.dll
```

#2- restart xamp

#Problem : when try to "composer update" print error:

```
 Problem 1
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.28, ..., 3.1.30] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.16.* -> satisfiable by phpoffice/pfice/phpspreadsheet[1.16.0].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.31, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpofficeoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.25.2].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.27 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.16 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[sheet[1.16.0, ..., 1.25.2].
    - maatwebsite/excel 3.1.26 requires phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.15 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[sheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.25.2].
    - maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.6) does not satisfy that reqat requirement.
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.15.0, ..., 1.25.2] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install orall or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqpEW.png)

Answer (score 0):

PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

For windows set your **extension_dir** path in **php.ini**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).