# Xampp Apache server shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, xampp

When using XAMPP I tried to start the APACHE server it gave me an error

```
0:39:59 AM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
10:40:00 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: running
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   Status change detected: stopped
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:40:02 AM  [Apache]   entire log window on the forums
```

Many people have said to check the Nestat to check if the ports were taken or not, but from the image below you can see that neither port 8080 or port 4433 are taken

[image]

And upon checking the error logs I saw this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_ftp.dll' (tried: C:\\Users\\Logan\\Desktop\\XAMPP\\php\\ext\\php_ftp.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\Users\\Logan\\Desktop\\XAMPP\\php\\ext\\php_php_ftp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the php.ini file, if the links in the file are correct?
Source: [PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library, when running unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156520/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-when-running-unit-tests)