# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Tags: php, apache

I've already downloaded `(php_printer.dll)` and moved it to

**`C:\xampp\php\ext`** directory

**download link:** [Click Here](http://www.dlldownloader.com/php_printer-dll/download/976d2ceb18a82fb6dc1b39eb177235c0/f8f728aadab2c37e7a7deb22ce009d4d/)

*php.ini*

> extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext\"
>
> extension=php_printer.dll

But in command prompt

> php -v

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll' - The specified module could not be found.in Unknown on line 0.
```

I've also restarted xampp after making changes in the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Check path manual if its correct `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll` Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027173/12232340

Comment: After editing of `php.ini` file you must restart your `xampp.` did you try this?

Comment: i've already done that stuff