# Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sockets.dll'

Tags: php, sockets, xampp

Ok, so when I run my php file it gives me this error:

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_sockets.dll'`

In my php.ini file, I've added the line "extension=php_sockets.dll" but it still gives me this error. I've searched many ways of solving this problem but they didn't work.

I've noticed someting in the error. It said this:

`C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_sockets.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.))`

Why does it say `php_php_socketsdll.dll`? How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably the [php.ini extension name change for php 7.2+](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/load-ext-by-name), you should use `sockets` as extension name. The prefix `php_` and the OS dependent library suffix `.dll` will be added, hence the name `php_php_sockets.dll.dll`. It's weird thought since the documentation only states it is *recommended* to use it.

Comment: I deleted the `extension=php_sockets.dll` line and uncommented de `extension=socket` line and it gave me the same errors...

Comment: Does `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_sockets.dll` actually exist? Also, check that your `extension_dir` entry in the php.ini has the [full path (absolute path) inclusive driveletter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25027173/3828957).

Comment: yes it does exist. Also, the full path was already correct.

Comment: @JoãoTeixeira  did you find the solution for this issue