# PHP 7.4 gives errors unable load dynamic libraries on Windows

Tags: php, php-extension

I am trying to run a cron job on PHP moodle website

I created the script file and created the .bat file that contains the following

```
C:/xampp2/php/php.exe C:/xampp2/htdocs/training/admin/cli/cron.php
```

then I tried to run it using cmd but I get the following error

```
C:\Users\amira>C:\xampp2\htdocs\training\cron.bat

C:\Users\amira>C:/xampp2/php/php.exe C:/xampp2/htdocs/training/admin/cli/cron.php
PHP Warning:  Failed loading Zend extension 'opcache' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\opcache (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_opcache.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'curl' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\curl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'fileinfo' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\fileinfo (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_fileinfo.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gd2' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\gd2 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_gd2.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'gettext' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\gettext (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_gettext.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imap' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\imap (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_imap.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mbstring' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\mbstring (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_mbstring.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'exif' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\exif (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_exif.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\mysqli (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_mysqli.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'openssl' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\openssl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\pdo_mysql (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlite' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\pdo_sqlite (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\sockets (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_sockets.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sodium' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\sodium (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_sodium.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlite3' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\sqlite3 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_sqlite3.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'xsl' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\xsl (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_xsl.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv_74_nts_x64' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\sqlsrv_74_nts_x64 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64' (tried: C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64 (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_nts_x64.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
!!! <p>Error: database driver problem detected</p>
<p>The site administrator should verify server configuration</p><p>PHP has not been properly configured with the MySQLi extension for it to communicate with MySQL. Please check your php.ini file or recompile PHP.</p> !!!
```

I checked my php.ini file and I already include the extensions

```
[PHP_MYSQLI]
extension=php_mysqli.dll


[PHP]
cgi.force_redirect = 0
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
fastcgi.impersonate = 1
fastcgi.logging = 0

extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=intl
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
intl.default_locale = en_utf8
extension=php_intl.dll


[opcache]
zend_extension = php_opcache.dll
opcache.enable = 1
opcache.memory_consumption = 128
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 10000
opcache.revalidate_freq = 60

; Required for Moodle
opcache.use_cwd = 1
opcache.validate_timestamps = 1
opcache.save_comments = 1
opcache.enable_file_override = 0

max_input_vars = 10000
```

can anyone please help ?

Comment: What is unclear about "The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_opcache.dll" ??  Did you check if the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP74\ext\php_opcache.dll` does exist?

Comment: Possible fix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25027013/how-to-fix-php-warning-php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-ext-php-cu

Comment: @Luuk I did not use anything from Plesk, I have xampp and the PHP folder inside it and the path of php.exe that I use from inside xampp

Comment: You could check which PHP.INI file is being used, see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558150/how-to-know-which-php-ini-is-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14558150/how-to-know-which-php-ini-is-used)